# How is the individual person affected by economic changes as a result of Brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, economy, brexit, trade

I have a few questions regarding the following topic: How is the individual person affected by economic changes as a result of Brexit?

1. How are people in the age between 25 and 35 predicted to be affected on the job market?
2. How are people in the age between 45 and 55 predicted to be affected on the job market?

Comment: As it hasn't happened yet, the answers to your questions are unknown.

Comment: @ouflak, the question asks about predictions. I'm sure there are both scientific studies and political manifestos with more or less credible numbers. A good answer would list several with different viewpoints.

Comment: @o.m. Are predictions based on events that haven't happened yet on topic?

Comment: @ouflak, two points here. I would think that it is on topic to talk about campaign pledges, political programs, or speeches if they concern the future. The economic impact of Brexit was certainly debated at length. And **if** it is OK to talk about those claims, surely it is appropriate to reality-check them against studies. Of course the answer should challenge if the study is really from a "disinterested academic" or from a party-affilated think tank ...

Comment: @o.m. "...if it is OK to talk about those claims, surely it is appropriate to reality-check them..." But *reality* doesn't begin to happen for another 43 days.

Comment: @ouflak, by this reasoning we could close Politics and move everything to History.

Comment: @o.m. Ummm... how could we move speculative discussion about the political ramifications resulting from something that hasn't happened yet into History? I'm not very familiar with that Exchange site. Is that what they do there?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone will have their EU citizenship forcefully removed sooner or later, which means the job market for them narrows from the entire EU to just the UK. Work in the EU will only be possible with a suitable visa, which makes them a less attractive candidate all other things being equal.

Comment: Are you sure? This may yet be negotiated, even if it is not yet part of any current proposal.

Comment: @ouflak not unless the UK is willing to do the same reciprocally for EU citizens.

Comment: Sure, fine with me. But it's all speculative now. We just don't know how things are going to work out. Unless somebody blurts something out over drinks in a bar, we can't even be sure what all is being considered right now.